# When use Bounded type parameter or type Interface directly

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

In case you need to pass an argument of an interface type to a method you could use two impl.

Use a bounded type parameter:

```
public static <I extends InterfaceObj> void isTrue(boolean expression, I interfaceobj) {
        if(!expression){
            throw new RunTimeException(interfaceobj);
        }}
```

Otherwise you could use the type of interface :

```
public static void isTrue(boolean expression, InterfaceObj interfaceobj) {
        if(!expression){
            throw new RunTimeException(interfaceobj);
        }
    }
```

Then if I have a class which implements InterfaceObj  I could use it in the first and second example so I don't see the difference, advantadges and disadvantages from one or other.

- What is it the difference in each case?
- When is it better to use one or other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From oracle :

> There may be times when you want to restrict the types that can be
>   used as type arguments in a parameterized type. For example, a method
>   that operates on numbers might only want to accept instances of Number
>   or its subclasses. This is what bounded type parameters are for.

Functionally, it is exactly the same thing since with a interface as parameter type, **it might also only want to accept instances of Number or its subclasses**.

Technically, it is slightly different since compiled classes should be different.

In your case, I would prefer use the raw interface type without wildcard since it's less verbose.

---

It doesn't mean that bounded type parameters in methods are useless.
It can indeed be useful when you use multiple bound type parameters.
Imagine that your method would accept a parameter at the condition that it belongs both to two specified types : `InterfaceObj` and `OtherInterfaceObj`.

With a interface type, to address this need, you should create another interface which extends these two interfaces and you would use it in your method such as :

```
public static  void isTrue(boolean expression, MyTwoInterfacesObj interfaceobj) {
  if (!expression) {
      throw new RuntimeException();
  }
}
```

With multiple bound type parameters, you don't need to create an additional interface. You can specify it such as :

```
public static <I extends InterfaceObj & OtherInterfaceObj> void isTrue(boolean expression, I interfaceobj) {
  if (!expression) {
      throw new RuntimeException();
  }
}
```

With two interfaces, restricting the parameter type on both of them is a little awkward, imagine with three or four interfaces and multiple possible mixes of them.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't see the difference, advantadges and disadvantages from one or
>   other.

I think you forgot about **Collections!**

If you have a Collection parameter, that's where the real advantage of *bounded type parameters* comes into play

In this method you can only pass a List which has instatiated like `List<InterfaceObj> list = new ArrayList<InterfaceObj>();`

```
public static void processList(List<InterfaceObj> input){
    //...
}
```

but if you use bounded parameterized generic, you can pass all below lists as inputs

```
List<InterfaceObj> list = new ArrayList<InterfaceObj>();
List<SubInterfaceObj> list = new ArrayList<SubInterfaceObj>();
List<SubSubInterfaceObj> list = new ArrayList<SubSubInterfaceObj>();

public static void processList(List<? extends InterfaceObj> input){
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that with the first, or *typed*, version the code in the method can know *which* exact subtype was passed, but the second version can not.

You would notice the difference more clearly if your methods returned a list of the same type as the parameter. Version one could return `List<I>` - a list whose type is the same as the parameter's (sub)type, but version two can only return a `List<InterfaceObj>` whose type is the supertype.